# Positioning of element with JS transform properties (CSS get's overwritten by JS)

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, position, css-position

I'm trying to position two images on top of eachother, and having one of them rotate on scroll while the other one is not rotating - which works, except i'm unable to position and scale my elements in my CSS. As soon as i start scrolling, the image with the JS jumps into the corner while the other one remains where it is. I believe it's because my JS overwrites my CSS properties, but is there any way of working around this? Can i position my two elements while maintaining my JS?

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("rotatelogo");
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var value = window.scrollY * 0.25;
    elem.style.transform = `translatex(-50%) translatey(-50%) rotate(${value}deg)`; 
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  background: darkblue;
}

.guide {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:-300px;
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="guide" style="position:relative">
    <img src="http://jakobnatorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/ARROW.png" style="position:fixed;"/>
    <img class="portfolio" id="rotatelogo" src="http://jakobnatorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/SELECTED-WORK-BEIGE.png" style="position:fixed"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I'v created a running [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). Feel free to edit if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove translate from your code.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("rotatelogo");
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var value = window.scrollY * 0.25;
    elem.style.transform = `rotate(${value}deg)`; 
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  background: darkblue;
}

.guide {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:-300px;
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="guide" style="position:relative">
    <img src="http://jakobnatorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/ARROW.png" style="position:fixed;"/>
    <img class="portfolio" id="rotatelogo" src="http://jakobnatorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/SELECTED-WORK-BEIGE.png" style="position:fixed"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to achieve by using`translatex(-50%) translatey(-50%)`, but this is causing the images center to be positioned on the top left corner of the parent element.
If you just use `` elem.style.transform = `rotate(${value}deg)`; `` it will rotate in place.